# WooCommerce Place Order button not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When clicking the “Place Order” button, the user is scrolled to the top of the page but no errors are given and WooCommerce doesn't record a sale. Further, no JS errors are shown in the console. I've unchecked “Force SSL” in WooCommerce settings. I've tried everything I can think of and spent hours on forums to no avail–hoping someone has some advice on this. Thanks for any help!

The site is here: https://lillabello.com/product/order-florals/

Answer (score 0):

This could be a theme or plug-in conflict. In the first instance, check your theme for WooCommerce compatibility. If not sure, try with a different theme. If that works, you will either need to switch themes or contact the theme developer support.

If if is not a theme conflict, disable ALL plug-ins (other than WooCommerce) and try. If that works, try re-enabling them one by one to identify the offending plug-in (and then remove + replace it with another one that doesn't conflict).

If that doesn't work, (deactivate and) delete the WooCommerce plug-in and then re-install it.

Hope one of the above fixes your problem.

(You can try the above methods in any order.)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I should have mentioned, I tried switching themes, plugins, and re-installing WC. I even rolled back to an older version of WC but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being fairly easy–someone had disabled their shipping zones so once I enabled those again, completing orders works.

Thanks for checking back in here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to just UNcheck "Enable Paypal Checkout" on the cart page

Comment: please use comment section to ask same or supplementary question